# Media query override orientation Portrait

Tags: css, media-queries

I am learning media query . I am trying to give different width for diverse devices from [this](http://mobiletest.me/) web Page . I building 6 media Query (without Samsung Galaxy ,it i will later to do …) , but them override my Desktop and Nexus Portrait .

The Media Query for this Devices;

```
/*   My Desktop    1280 x 1024 */

@media only screen and (min-width: 65em) and (max-width: 80em) {  
body {

/* Tablet iPad 4 generation & iPad air, Portrait */

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em) and (orientation: portrait)  {


/* Nokia Lumia 920  */

@media only screen and (max-width : 47.5em) and (orientation : portrait) {

/* Tablet Nexus 7  (Portrait) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 38em) and (orientation: portrait){


/* Smartphones iPhone 3-4-5(Portrait)  */

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) 
          and (max-width: 30em) 
          and (orientation: portrait){
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/rPaeaR) all Media Query Code from **tablet_index.css** .

The meta tags;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I using PHP Code to import/include to CSS File ;

```
<style>
<?php 

     include 'CSS/me.css';
     include 'CSS/tablet_index.css';
?>
</style>
```

I am since a Week who to try to Display them... , can please anyone help me to solve this Problem , very Thanks !

Comment: dont really understand what you are trying to do here as all of your media queries are empty and dont have closing tag

Comment: Here my all Media Query Code https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/rPaeaR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that problem....

on my  **Desktop** `@media only screen and (min-width: 65em) and (max-width: 80em) {`

i wrote `grid-gap` when should to write `grid-row-gap` .

Later on my **Nexus** `@media only screen and (max-width: 38em) and (orientation: portrait){`

Change my **Hover**;

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {

  left: 80px;
  top: 182px; 
}
```